# Generate log statement from method signature

Tags: logging, android-studio, intellij-idea

Is there a convinient way to auto-create Log statements according to method signature?

Press some shortcut and it would insert the statement at the caret.

I'm looking for something similiar to below example:

```
public void myMethod(String first, int second, Object third) {
    Log.e(TAG, "myMethod() first=" + first  + ", second=" + second + ", third=" + third);

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just saw something like that in the Android Studio for Experts Video on the Android Developers Channel:

https://youtu.be/Y2GC6P5hPeA?t=314

In short:

You use the `logm` live-template at the start of your method and it generates a logging-call for the method-entry.

For this you can generate the `TAG`-constant at the beginning of the class-body with the `logt`-template (the string-value will be the simple classname).

Another live-template `logr` exists to log the method-return value at the end of the method right before the return-statement (inserted at the caret-position).

Comment: these are good ... but unfortunately not widely known. Is there some page you know of listing all live templates?

Comment: Search the settings in Android Studio for "live template" and there you can inspect and manage all existing live-templates. You can even add your own live-templates and have the source of all pre-existing templates as a "template" (pun intended).

Comment: For example, logm is defined as:

    android.util.Log.d(TAG, "$METHOD_NAME$() called with: " +  $args$);